# Block CSS positioning text to the bottom

Tags: html, css

I have a basic grid of blocks - and on one design I am keen to position the text at the bottom. The problem I am having is either setting a class on this kind of block that will use the full width of the height like 100% -- and then position absolute bottom the text.

//what it looks like currently

[image]

//what I am trying to ensure it looks like

[image]

Mark up looks like this

```
<div class="element-container ant-col-xs-24 ant-col-sm-12 ant-col-md-6" style="position: absolute; left: 614px; top: 300px;">

    <div class="element-wrapper">
        <div class="contents-wrapper">
            <div class="title">We are always here to help</div>
            <div class="contents">
                <div>
                    <p class="white-text absolute-bottom">When to seek support call 0202 000 000</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contents-background">
            <img class="small" src="http://www.dustydavis.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Home-Buying-1.jpg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

scss

```
.elements {

    .element-container{
        width: 200px;

        .element-wrapper{
            background: #ffffff;
            border: 1px solid black;
            height: 280px;

            margin:10px;

            .contents-wrapper{
                position: relative;
                z-index: 1;

                .title{
                    padding:10px;
                    background: #676766;
                    color: #ffffff;
                }
                .contents{
                    padding:10px;
                }
            }

            .contents-background{
              margin:10px;
              position: absolute;
              left: 1px;
              bottom: 1px;
              right: 1px;
              top: 1px;
              overflow: hidden;
              z-index: 0;

              img{


                &

                &.small{
                    width: auto;
                    height: 100%;                   
                }

              }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I've got a base jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/111/

```css
.demowrap{
 width: 600px;
 height: 600px;
    position: relative;
 border:1px solid red;
}
.elements {

}


.element-container{
width: 280px;/*demo width*/


}

.element-wrapper{
background: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid black;
height: 280px;

margin:10px;

}

.contents-wrapper{
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}

.contents-wrapper .title{
 padding:10px;
 background: #676766;
 color: #ffffff;
}


 .contents-wrapper .contents{
 padding:10px;
}

.contents-background{
  margin:10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  right: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}

.contents-background img.large{
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;          
}

.contents-background img.small{
 width: auto;
 height: 100%;          
}
```

```html
<div class="demowrap">

<div class="element-container ant-col-xs-24 ant-col-sm-12 ant-col-md-6" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">

<div class="element-wrapper">
 <div class="contents-wrapper">
  <div class="title">We are always here to help</div>
  <div class="contents">
   <div>
    <p class="white-text absolute-bottom">When to seek support call 0202 000 000</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="contents-background">
  <img class="small" src="http://www.dustydavis.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Home-Buying-1.jpg"></div>
 </div>
</div>


<div class="element-container ant-col-xs-24 ant-col-sm-12 ant-col-md-6" style="position: absolute; left: 300px; top: 0px;">

<div class="element-wrapper">
 <div class="contents-wrapper">
  <div class="title">Unaffected sister block</div>
  <div class="contents">
   <div>
    <p>Another demo block that just stays unaffected</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

</div>



</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a little confused as to what exactly you're trying to accomplish. Your fiddle doesn't match what you supposedly currently have, and there's no reference to any pink elements. Are you just trying to align the text to the bottom of the image?

Comment: -- yes - just trying to align the text to the bottom -- but this css is shared across other blocks - which don't feature this snap to the bottom aspect -- . the jsfiddle isn't taking on the scss? -- The pink design is more from an actual design reference -- but my concern is toggling the markup/adding a class or so to achieve this affect - cleanly

Comment: @ObsidianAge - just updated my demo -- two sister blocks -- one looking to position the text snapped to the bottom -- the other remains the same.

Comment: .contents-wrapper : 100% ---  .contents: 100%   -- div : position: absolute; bottom:0;

Comment: ^ that div containing the text -- is part of the shell of a react component - so I may place other relative items in there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried positioning `.contents` ? If `.content-wrapper` is 100% height, you should be able to align `.contents` to the bottom.

```
.contents-wrapper {
  height: 100%; // add
}
.contents {
  position: absolute; // add
  bottom: 0; // add
}
```

You could also lose the extra `div`

Comment: -- well that will impact - other shared aspects -- also it doesn't work like that for relative positioned divs -- 100% height etc.. if the height was given a fixed value like 200px then sure -- this is sound logic

Comment: @TheOldCounty the parent element `.element-wrapper` has a fixed height. hens the suggestion

Comment: Sure -- but then to fix the height again inside a child element - is there a way to avoid that.. etc..

Comment: -- I don't think setting 100% height in your contents-wrapper will have any affect

Comment: just updated my demo -- two sister blocks -- one looking to position the text snapped to the bottom -- the other remains the same.

Comment: "You could also lose the extra div" -- no that's the react wrapped part of the component